# CGI Scripts display as text on OSX 10.9

Tags: scripting, cgi, osx-mavericks

These scripts executed perfectly on "Lion". When I upgraded to "Mavericks" they only display as text. The scripts still execute (from the command line) perfectly, but when called from the browser you get the text (not the web page that it should be generating).

A simple step-by-step would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you "call" it from a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to run these in a browser? Have you made sure that the web worker executing the script has the correct level of permissions required to do so?